# Do Pentecostals include the Old Testament in their Bible? Or do they only follow the New Testament?

Tags: bible, old-testament, new-testament, canon, pentecostalism

I have a church near my home, and it's called the New Testament church. So, just wondering if their Bible doesn't have the Old Testament.

Comment: All Pentecostal denominations, that I'm aware of, use the Protestant [Canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_canon) which includes the Old Testament. A "New Testament church" really the refers to the Biblical model of the church as the "Church" of the Old Testament is actually Israel - it's used to distinguish from Churches that follow traditions *not* found in the bible. Is this all you really wanted to know?  (because "follow" is an ambiguous term that could mean other things as well).

Comment: Yeah, that's all I wanted to know. Thanks for the answer :).

Comment: Ok, you're welcome and welcome to the site! Please check out the [tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and [how we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites?s=1|0.7118) when you have a chance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about one specific Church location.  There are plenty of one-offs that don't believe what most Christianity believes, and to know for sure about this one location, you'd have to stop in there and ask. This is too specific for this site.

Comment: I attend an Assemblies of God church, and have attended many Pentecostal churches, and every one I've come across have always included both the New and Old Testaments.

Comment: @bruisedreed Could you make that an answer, or is the question too broad pere David Stratton's comment?  You seem to have satisfied Aj334's question, and others may have a similar question about churches that present themselves similarly. (There is one a few miles from our house that says "A New Testament Church" on the sign outside).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my previous [comment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/54976/do-pentecostals-include-the-old-testament-in-their-bible-or-do-they-only-follow#comment151192_54976), to the best of my knowledge, all Pentecostal denominations use the regular [Protestant canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protestant_Bible) which includes the 39 books that are frequently thought of as the Old Testament. This excludes the 7 [Deuterocanonical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterocanonical_books) books that are included in the Catholic and Orthodox canons.

The term "New Testament Church" is fairly common parlance amongst Pentecostals (but by no means restricted to just them - *[eg](https://bible.org/seriespage/1-what-new-testament-church)*), so it's not particularly suprising that a particular congregation may be named as such. It's not any kind of statement against "following the Old Testament" as such, but it's more based on:

- The people of God in the Old Testament are not usually referred to as "the Church", but rather as Israel.
- It's a subtle acknowledgement of the belief that many modern churches have adopted beliefs, traditions and practices that do not have a biblical basis and have thus departed from the Church found in the New Testament which is believed to be what we should be aiming to return to as our model.